# Turning two lists of strings into keyword arguments

Tags: ruby

How can I turn these two lists of strings into keyword arguments?

```
["foo", "bar", "fizz"], ["1", "2", "buzz"]
```

into

```
(foo: "1", bar: "2", fizz: "buzz")
```

Comment: You cannot do that. That is not an object. Or, do you mean how to pass parameters like that to a method?

Comment: the result you look for is invalid

Comment: Do you mean: {foo: "1", bar: "2", fizz: "buzz"}? Or do you want a string with parens: '(foo: "1", bar: "2", fizz: "buzz")'?

Comment: I think he wants to use them as keyword arguments.

Comment: Do you mean to a Hash with those properties, e.g. `{ :foo => "1", ... }` or do you mean a string with that literal content?

Comment: Downvote is mine, for a poorly-worded question and failure to respond to the above comments with an edit. I'll withdraw the downvote if you edit to address the issues voiced. Many readers may see your question in future. You owe it to them as well as to today's readers to fix your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could hash the two lists:

```
a = ["foo", "bar", "fizz"]
b = ["1", "2", "buzz"]
res = Hash[a.zip b]
```

`res` would be: `{"foo"=>"1", "bar"=>"2", "fizz"=>"buzz"}`

Comment: You'll never know. (Maybe because you didn't change the keys to symbols, which is trivial.) Such is life.

Comment: Although SO does say that you should comment about why you downvote. It's part of community courtesy.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the strings to symbols and make a hash out of it, you can do:

```
strings = ["foo", "bar", "fizz"]
symbols = strings.map(&:to_sym)
integers = ["1","2","3"]

Hash[symbols.zip(integers)]
```

You will get `{foo: "1", bar: "2", fizz: "buzz"}` as desired.

Comment: Why would you want to [make a hash of it](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/make_a_hash_of)?

Answer (score 0):

Not as clean or as small as the other answers but this works.. and converts to symbols. Aaron-coding provided a nice shorthand way!

```
w = ["foo", "bar", "fizz"] 
w2 = ["1", "2", "buzz"]
c = 0
h = Hash.new { |hash, sym| hash[sym] }

w.each do |x|
    h[x.to_sym] = w2[c]
    c += 1
end

puts h
```

Answer (score -1):

`words = ["foo", "bar", "fizz"]`

`integers = ["1","2","3"]`

You can try this: `Hash[words.zip(integers)]`

Comment: Or `words.zip(integers).to_h` in a newer Ruby.

Comment: Note that the OP's integers are actually strings.

Comment: ...to be converted to symbols.